# How do I find source of error in zone.js - 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm upgraded my Angular version from 4 to 5 and, while working out some kinks, I noticed I'm getting an error that I can't seem to track down. This may have nothing to do with the upgrade and may have to do with my data being too old (falling outside of the selection range). But I'm getting the following strack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at backend.js:9584
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at getDependencies (backend.js:9583)
    at Object.exports.transform (backend.js:9504)
    at backend.js:9511
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at transformChildren (backend.js:9510)
    at Object.exports.transform (backend.js:9526)
    at backend.js:9511
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

The error is being caught in zone.js here:

```
    Zone.prototype.runTask = function (task, applyThis, applyArgs) {
        if (task.zone != this) {
            throw new Error('A task can only be run in the zone of creation! (Creation: ' +
                (task.zone || NO_ZONE).name + '; Execution: ' + this.name + ')');
        }
        // https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/778, sometimes eventTask
        // will run in notScheduled(canceled) state, we should not try to
        // run such kind of task but just return
        // we have to define an variable here, if not
        // typescript compiler will complain below
        var isNotScheduled = task.state === notScheduled;
        if (isNotScheduled && task.type === eventTask) {
            return;
        }
        var reEntryGuard = task.state != running;
        reEntryGuard && task._transitionTo(running, scheduled);
        task.runCount++;
        var previousTask = _currentTask;
        _currentTask = task;
        _currentZoneFrame = { parent: _currentZoneFrame, zone: this };
        try {
            if (task.type == macroTask && task.data && !task.data.isPeriodic) {
                task.cancelFn = null;
            }
            try {
                return this._zoneDelegate.invokeTask(this, task, applyThis, applyArgs);
            }
            catch (error) {
                if (this._zoneDelegate.handleError(this, error)) {
                    // >>>>> Caught and rethrown here:
                    throw error;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have naturally been looking at my uses of the "filter" function to make sure they're guarded to prevent this type of error. I haven't found a problem with that (yet). Any ideas on how to track down the source of this type of error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess u too are using Augury and that is causing this error.
Uninstall it and error will be gone.
Link for your help
https://github.com/rangle/augury/issues/1255

Comment: Why are you doing this to me Augury? Thanks for your help Rachit!